# Getting Ubuntu error while taking package manager

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

This is the error im getting while opening package manager.
My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 14.04 TLS.

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList     /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Try `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf && sudo apt-get update` as seen on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=863742

Comment: getting  a response like this

    rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Is a directory

Comment: Try `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vrf  && sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial && sudo apt-get update`